# IgniteRdd's savepairs method for reading parquet files

Tags: caching, apache-spark, rdd, ignite

I have made a small impl in order to read parquet files and store the items into cache. So I wrote:

```
val df= sqlContext.read.
        parquet(hdfsFolder).
        select("a","b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
val columnsSeq= Seq("a","b", "c", "d", "e", "f")

val values = df.map(row => (row.getAs[String]("a"), row.getValuesMap(columnsSeq))).
  groupByKey(1024).
  map(row => (row._1 , row._2.toList.asJava ))

//put them into cache

val igniteContext = new IgniteContext(sc, cacheConfigPath)

val sharedRdd = igniteContext.fromCache(cacheName)

sharedRdd.savePairs(values)
```

But the last line "sharedRdd.savePairs(values)" gives the compileerror:

> found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String,
>   java.util.List[Map[String,Nothing]])]  required:
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Nothing, Nothing)] Note: (String,
>   java.util.List[Map[String,Nothing]]) >: (Nothing, Nothing), but class
>   RDD is invariant in type T. You may wish to define T as -T instead.
>   (SLS 4.5)
>       sharedRdd.savePairs(values)

I could not found any ways to overcome this error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create `IgniteRDD` with proper typing:

```
val sharedRdd = igniteContext.fromCache[String, java.util.List[Map[String,Nothing]]](cacheName)
```